# Select last row and move it to the last column of the previous row

Tags: vba, excel

This is a bit of an odd question which I don't manage to find an answer to:
I would like to select the last row (maybe using `Cells(Rows.Count, Column.Count).End(xlUp).Row`) and move it to the end of the previous row.

I was thinking to use something similar as my transpose function (copy/paste):

```
Dim r As Range, N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set r = Cells(N, Column.Count).EntireRow
r.Copy
Cells(N + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
r.Delete
```

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image]

Has someone done something similar and is willing to share some help/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
Range(Cells(N, 1), Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cut Cells(N - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)
```

Here is the breakdown

- Determine the last row: `N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row`
- Create a range from the first cell to the last cell in the column

  - First Cell: `Cells(N, 1)`
  - Last Cell:  `Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)`
- Create a range reference to the last used column in the row above and move the reference one column to the right

  - `Cells(N - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)`
  - Cut the first range and paste it to the second range
  - `Range(Cells(N, 1), Cells(N, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cut Destination:=Cells(N - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1)`

Comment: It worked like a charm! Would you mind explaining the rationale behind the last line of code?

Comment: I added a breakdown to my answer.  Thanks for the check!

Comment: Thank YOU for helping out :)